# Is it possible to pass number of times invocation is met as parameter to a unit test class method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I have a unit test class method that currently takes 1 parameter but I want to extend it to receive 2 parameters with the latter being the number of times invocation is met on a mock object.
What I currently have is something like this, which doesn't compile successfully due to errors

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("", Times.Never)]
[InlineData("test", Times.Once)]
public async void PostAsync_SendAsync_VerifyOnce(string id, Times outcome)
{
    var mockClients = new Mock<IHubClients>();
...
...
...
    mockClients.Verify(clients => clients.Client(id), outcome);
}
```

Is it possible to achieve something like this? So in theory both tests here should pass, the first will never be invocated as the first parameter is blank and the second test will be invocated once as the parameter is valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `Times.Exactly` method:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("", 0)]
[InlineData("test", 1)]
public async void PostAsync_SendAsync_VerifyOnce(string id, int expectedCalls)
{
    var mockClients = new Mock<IHubClients>();
...
...
...
    mockClients.Verify(clients => clients.Client(id), Times.Exactly(expectedCalls));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `TheoryData` and bind it to your test via a `MemberDataAttribute`, that allows to make those `Times.Once()` and `Times.Never()` method calls.

It also allows other scenarios like `AtLeast` and `AtMost`.

```
public static TheoryData GetTestCases()
{
    return new TheoryData<string, Times>()
    {
        { "", Times.Never() },
        { "test", Times.Once() }
    };
}

[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(GetTestCases))]
public void PostAsyncSendAsyncVerifyOnce(string id, Times outcome)
{
    var mockClients = new Mock<IHubClients>();
    // ...
    mockClients.Verify(clients => clients.Client(id), outcome);
}
```